# Getting nth child value of element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to add '1' to the id conCol to make it conCol1. Please can someone tell me how I go about this because my statement below doesn't work. Also, is it possible to get the value of "first-column" i.e Condition #0 to make it Condition #1?

```
newElem.children('select :nth-child(2)').attr('id', 'conCol' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);

<tr id="condition1" class="clonedInput">
              <td class="first-column">Condition #0</td>
              <td><span style="float:left; padding-right: 10px;">
                <select id="conCol" name="conCol" class="standard_select" style="width:147px; background:#fff;">
```

Comment: are you trying to get the `select` tag or are you trying to get the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `newElem` is the `tr` element (wrapped in jQuery):

```
newElem.find('select').attr('id', 'conCol' + newNum).attr('name', 'conCol' + newNum);
newElem.find('.first-column').text('Condition #1');
```

Documentation for [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)